# Error: File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK

Tags: pdftex

pdflatex gives me this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\376\377\000M\000o\000d\000e\000l\000o\000s\000\040\000d\000e\000\04\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.26 \begin{document}
```

I already removed all.aux .bbl and .lof file in the whole directory tree:

```
del /s *.aux *.bbl *.lof
```

I  removed all contents from the file . Here is the file as it is now:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}


\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

%\usepackage[a4paper,includeall,bindingoffset=0cm,margin=2cm,marginparsep=0cm,marginparwidth=0cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}





\begin{document}
NNOTHING
\frontmatter
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{References/predoc.bib}
\end{document}
```

Previousunsuccessful compilations were with a lot more code.
Where can I look for the cause?

Comment: Just delete the auxiliary files and you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was the .out file.  So now I remove all auxiliary files before compiling. I use this batch file to compile:

```
del /s *.aux *.bbl *.lof *.out *.toc
cls
pdflatex.exe main.tex
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your document will never finish if you always delete the auxiliary files. They are needed to resolve references and to build the toc etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution could be  changing the main file's  name (or your project name); then  all auxiliary files will automatically  become unrelated with your project, i.e.,will in effect   disappear, i.e  become invisible to the compiler. Note that you  may still need  to delete auxiliary files  related with other files of the project, such as \input{}, or rename those files.

Comment: The simplest solution, I keep pressing enter enter and the error disappears on the next run